# PayPal Sandbox Notifications Problem

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have a .NET site which integrates with PayPal.  I am currently working with the Sandbox, and with recurring subscriptions.

I have created my buttons, and I am able to subscribe with them.  I see the money go out of my test user accounts and into my test business account.  I receive notifications back to my notification URL...all good.

My buttons are currently set to recur subscribe payment every day.

**My problem is that the recurring payments are never made, and I never receive any notifications.**

Everything looks good in the Sandbox...all of my subscriptions appear active in the business account profile, and all of the buttons look correct.

NOTE: I used to get many recurring notifications when I was in early development and failed to unsubscribe.  I cleaned out my accounts by resetting them, and I now unsubscribe correctly, but I don't get notifications beyond the initial signup.

Questions:

1. Any ideas?  Has anyone else seen this issue?
2. What is the best way to ask for help with this other than SO?
3. Should I delete and recreate all of my test accounts?  I have
   tried to reset them all, with no change in behavior.

**UPDATE:** The problem isn't me.  I found out by browsing the forums on x.com that PayPal subscription notifications in the Sandbox has been down for over a week!!!!!  Not good, but the problem wasn't me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually currently dealing with their recurring payments API as well.

When working with their DoDirectPayment API, the money wasn't always transferred from test account to test account. However, after switching to live mode, every thing worked fine. Although, I did receive payment notifications in sandbox mode.

To be more helpful, I would suggest registering at [x.com](http://www.x.com). There, the forums are moderated by PayPal technicians, and can provide helpful insight and well-suited solutions for your problems. They can also personally check your sandbox accounts for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from what you say that you are receiving an  IPN for the initial payment but no recurring IPNs. In that case I would strongly suspect that the recurrence is not being setup correctly.

Can you check the subscriptions?